# qt.labs.handlers not found

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I am trying to use qml handlers for the first time. 
import Qt.labs.handlers 1.0 is not working

My Qt version is 5.13.0 MingW32/64 . Using on windows 10.

snapshot 1 of error

[image]

snapshot of qt.labs identified modules

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickhandlers-index.html) points out:

> **In Qt 5.10, these handlers were introduced in a separate
>   Qt.labs.handlers module. Now they are included with Qt Quick since
>   5.12**. The pre-existing Keys attached property is similar in concept, so we refer to the pointing-device-oriented handlers plus Keys
>   together as the set of Input Handlers. We expect to offer more
>   attached-property use cases in future versions of Qt.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So in Qt 5.13 it is no longer necessary to import module `Qt.labs.handlers 1.0` since it has been moved to module `QtQuick 2.13`.